# Automation Script: Click on "Cancel" button on alert window by Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I would like to know is there any way to select(click on) Cancel button on alert window?

I used:

```
@browser.choose_cancel_on_next_confirmation()
@browser.click("//td[text() = 'mailik@mm.com']/../td//a[text()='Delete']")
```

Comment: Please be more precise in your question, we don't know enough to really help you

Comment: What framework is this and what is the context?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything else and assuming you're now working with selenium webdriver 2...

I'm assuming @browser is the webdriver object...

You need to use the switch_to method to change focus to the alert box and dismiss it

```
alert = @browser.switch_to.alert
alert.dismiss
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Alert.html#dismiss-instance_method